# Can a database be created with no user and/or owner?

Tags: mysql, configuration

Maybe this is a good or a bad question but in my Google research I wasn't able to find out a good answer (maybe because I suck at performing a good search). In a few words:

- can a DB be created without a user and/or owner?

I am trying to answer a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002216/codeigniter-showing-this-page-is-not-working-when-tried-to-load-database) and the user has shared it DB configuration and something caught my attention:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'gotche';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

The database does not have a username!

Regardless the DB used - which is in scenario is MySQL (don't know the version) - is this possible?

I don't think the username and password were removed for security reasons: It would be better to change it to something like `*****` - in that case everyone would know there is a username/password but I can ask the user if that's the reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL allows for a blank user with a blank password (anonymous access) to connect.

See [Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/default-privileges.html)

> If accounts for anonymous users were created, these have an empty user
>   name. The anonymous accounts have no password, so anyone can use them
>   to connect to the MySQL server.

---

Besides that, MySQL does not have the concept of "database owner", like SQL Server and Postgres do. There is a privilege system, where users can be assigned various types of access to databases, tables, etc, with `GRANT` statement.